# How to add an initial delay to autoplay in React Slick slider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, slick.js, react-slick

I created 3 image sliders using the react-slick-slider plugin in my React app. All 3 have their autoplay set to true, but I want to add a delay to 2 of the sliders so that autoplay kicks in one and two seconds later respectively to achieve the "staggering transition" effect.

While this is fairly easy to achieve in jQuery by using 'setTimeOut' function, however, I'd like to learn the 'react'/'javascript' way of doing things. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my component setup:

```
import React from 'react'
import Slider from 'react-slick'

import './art-slider.sass'

const settings = {
  arrows: false,
  dots: false,
  pauseOnHover: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 3000,
  autoplay: true,
  fade: true,
  variableWidth: false,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
}

const Art = () => (
  <div className="art-board">
    <Slider {...settings}>
      <div>
        <div className="slider-1">
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className="slider-2">
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className="slider-3">
      </div>
    </Slider>
    <Slider {...settings}>
      <div>
        <div className="slider-4">
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className="slider-5">
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className="slider-6">
      </div>
    </Slider>
    <Slider {...settings}>
      <div>
        <div className="slider-7">
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className="slider-8">
      </div>
      <div>
        <div className="slider-9">
      </div>
    </Slider>
  </div>
)

export default Art
```

Answer (score 2):

Not the cleanest, but maybe try something like this?

```js
import React from 'react'
import Slider from 'react-slick'

var settings = {
  infinite: true,
  cssEase: "linear",
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1
}

var slider1Settings = { ...settings, autoplaySpeed: 1000 }
var slider2Settings = { ...settings, autoplaySpeed: 2000 }

class Carousel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.delay = this.delay.bind(this)
  }

  delay(slider, amount) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      slider.slickPlay()
    }, amount)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.delay(this.slider1, 3000)
    this.delay(this.slider2, 1000)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="art-board">
        <Slider {...settings}>
          <div>
            <div className="slider-1">1</div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div className="slider-2">2</div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div className="slider-3">3</div>
          </div>
        </Slider>
        <Slider {...slider1Settings} ref={slider1 => (this.slider1 = slider1)}>
          <div>
            <div className="slider-4">4</div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div className="slider-5">5</div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div className="slider-6">6</div>
          </div>
        </Slider>
        <Slider {...slider2Settings} ref={slider2 => (this.slider2 = slider2)}>
          <div>
            <div className="slider-7">7</div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div className="slider-8">8</div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div className="slider-9">9</div>
          </div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Carousel
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something along the lines of this:

```
import React from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
export default class SimpleSlider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      arrows: false,
      dots: false,
      pauseOnHover: false,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 1000,
      autoplay: true,
      fade: false,
      variableWidth: false,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState(
        {
          autoplay: false
        },
        console.log(this.state)
      );
    }, 5000);
  }

  render() {
    var settings = {
      arrows: false,
      dots: false,
      pauseOnHover: false,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 1000,
      autoplay: true,
      fade: false,
      variableWidth: false,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <Slider {...settings}>
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>6</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
        <Slider {...this.state}>
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>6</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
        <Slider {...this.state}>
          <div>
            <h3>1</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>2</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>3</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>4</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>5</h3>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3>6</h3>
          </div>
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your suggestion but it does not seem to work. The autoplay stops working for the slider with the {...delayedSettings}

Comment: It seems to be an issue with react-slick not updating the `autoplay` prop to true.  Here is a jsbin of setting `autoplay: true` to `autoplay: false` working: https://codesandbox.io/s/qz2z083wm4

Here is the source code: https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/blob/48c93ed36cfb58991e6bf4d34a1a588094281d12/src/inner-slider.js

Unfortunately, you'll have to fork the repo and make modifications for it to update the autoplay prop to play on prop change for it to work the way you want it to.  Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you this solution:

set the autoplay value for the last two sliders as part of the state, init to false and then `onComponentDidMount` set a timeout of 2 and update the state to true.

some snippets of code:

```js
constructor() {
  this.state = {
    autoplay: false,
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({
      autoplay: true,
    });
  }, 2000);
}

render () {
  <Slider {...settings}> ...</Slider>
  <Slider {...settings} autoplay={this.state.autoplay}> ...</Slider>
  <Slider {...settings} autoplay={this.state.autoplay}> ...</Slider>

}
```

Comment: I dont know if its my setup or anything, I followed your suggestion but the autoplay does not even start:/

Answer (score 0):

Updating autoplay prop is not working, it seems react-slick does not get re-initialised on updating autoplay prop. For a workaround, you can try updating autoplaySpeed prop instead.

For example, set autoplaySpeed to some greater time and update to desired time on DOM load:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = { 
      isDOMReady: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('load', this.startSlider);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('load', this.startSlider);
  }

  startSlider = () => {
    this.setState({ isDOMReady: true });
  }

  render() {
    const { isDOMReady } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="home-section">
        <div className="home-pic">
          <Slider
            {...HomeSliderConfig}
            autoplaySpeed={isDOMReady ? HomeSliderConfig.autoplaySpeed : 15000}
          >
            // Your slides
          </Slider>
        </div>
     </div>
   );
}
```